# What does "Member names cant be the same as their enclosing type" mean?

Tags: c#

"Member names cant be the same as their enclosing type". How would I re-arrange this code to make it run?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace works
{

    class Enemy : Character
    {

        Character Hero = new Character();

        Character Enemy = new Character();

        public override void Die()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("[0] has killed the enemy!", mST_Name);
        }

        public override void TakeDamage()

        {
            Enemy.mIN_HitPoints -= Hero.mIN_Strength;

            Console.WriteLine("Your enemy has been hit and has {0} HP left!", mIN_HitPoints);

            if (mIN_HitPoints == 0)
            {
                Die();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The point of this code is to simulate a RPG style game. Note that "enemy" is needed in this line of code for damage calculations.

Comment: What part of "Member names cant be the same as their enclosing type" is unclear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are specifying a property with the same name as the enclosing class. This is not allowed in C# and you have to choose a different name.

```
class Enemy
{
    Character Enemy = new Character(); // choose other name instead of "Enemy"
}
```

Read more on [**MSDN**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdhfk2xk.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: Thank you for answering but "enemy"  is needed in this line of code (for damage calculation).

Comment: Simply rename it to something different. It sometimes isn't pretty, but you'll just have to do it.

Comment: OMG i feel like a fool! sorry, im kinda new to c#. My code works now...thanks :)

Comment: So they're really not just "enemy"... in this case they're really enemy_target (or whatever other meaningful name you come up with.  They're not just a random enemy on the entire battlefield, they're the SPECIFIC enemy that you're interacting with)